# Handling <select> form parameter in node.js/express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a form that has a multi-select control. When I submit the form the URL requested is something like this

http://www.domain.com/?carlist=saab&carlist=opel

The same param-name "carlist" is passed so when I use req.param('carlist') it returns only "opel".

How can I handle multi-select form parameter in node.js/express?

```
 <select name="carlist" form="carform" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="opel">Opel</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/api#req.query):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var query = req.query;

  console.log(query.carlist); // [ 'opel', 'saab' ]
});
```